# Hide Subclass of a Footable Using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have here a table which has the following subclasses. All I want is to hide the last subclass using jquery.

[image: Please help. Thank you.]

this is what i tried:-

```
$('#availableagency2.table.table-responsive.table-hover.foot‌​able.footable-1.foot‌​able-filtering.foota‌​ble-filtering-right.‌​footable-paging.foot‌​able-paging-center.f‌​ootable-2.breakpoint‌​.breakpoint-lg tfoot tr.footable-paging td ul.pagination li.footable-page-nav a.footable-page-link').hide()
```

Comment: Add relevant code here at SO, not a link to picture @Queen

Comment: $('#availableagency2.table.table-responsive.table-hover.footable.footable-1.footable-filtering.footable-filtering-right.footable-paging.footable-paging-center.footable-2.breakpoint.breakpoint-lg tfoot tr.footable-paging td ul.pagination li.footable-page-nav a.footable-page-link').hide()

Comment: That's my code but it doesn't work.

Comment: [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/) are you looking for something like this?

Comment: @QueenElizabeth  it's not clear what you want to hide and from where to hide? Image also is not a good thing for asking question

Comment: I just want to hide the last subclass which is the "footable-page-link"

Comment: so it's not hide. it's removeClass()